# Aurelia Dependency Injection Testing

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia, jspm

I've been working in aurelia app and I'm getting an error while testing.

I'm trying to use `aurelia-dependency-injection` which is already a dependency of other packages which I'm including via `jspm` like `aurelia-framework`, `aurelia-router`, `aurelia-templating-resources`, `aurelia-templating-router` and when I try to inject it just works fine on my browser. However, when I try to test using Karma, it says

```
27 05 2016 09:45:18.202:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/aurelia-dependency-injection.js
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading /home/cyberkiller/test_project/aurelia-dependency-injection.js
Error loading /home/cyberkiller/test_project/aurelia-dependency-injection.js as "aurelia-dependency-injection" from /home/cyberkiller/test_project/src/users/list.ts
```

My `package.json` has the following jspm dependencies:

```json
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.3",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.5",
      "fetch": "github:github/fetch@^0.11.0",
      "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@^4.6.1",
      "simple-line-icons": "npm:simple-line-icons@^2.2.4",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
```

I did find a workaround, which is to add `aurelia-dependency-injection` explicitly as a dependency in my `package.json` like

`"aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3"`

Which makes my `package.json` look like:

```json
"jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3",
      "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.3",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.5",
      "fetch": "github:github/fetch@^0.11.0",
      "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@^4.6.1",
      "simple-line-icons": "npm:simple-line-icons@^2.2.4",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
```

When I update everything and build and run test, it no longer complains and it executes successfully. However I'm not sure if this is just a workaround, or the way to do it. Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: How do you import the dependency injection? If you use this: `import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';`, your solution should be the right way. Karma isn't build for Aurelia, but the Aurelia-framework is build for DI, so maybe Aurelia knows about a workaround that Karma does not.

Comment: You could also use the Aurelia framework though: this works for me `import {inject, Container} from 'aurelia-framework';` ánd I can run my unit-tests.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned this before, I'm using TypeScript and I'm importing auto inject this way: `import {autoinject} from "aurelia-dependency-injection";`

Comment: Have you included the node/jspm modules folder in your karma config? I assume you are using a test setup that already works (like skeleton/plugin skeleton?)